# MVC render partial view using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need your help.

I'm trying to render partial view using ajax. But it fails.
here is code:

```
 //I have action to get data
 public ActionResult ReturnPartial()
    {
                return PartialView("_LogIn");
    }

 //here is ajax
     <p onclick="Func1()">Log In</p>

<div id="here"></div>

<script>
    function Func1() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@(Url.Action("ReturnPartial", "Registration"))',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#here").html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("Failed to retrieve view");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

When I click Log In, it alters message: "Failed to retrieve view";

Thank you for your attention and please help me

Comment: If the Ajax Request fail, it is related to your server-side code. The response returned should be either a client mistake (HTTP 4xx) or a server error (HTTP 5xx).

I do not use .NET, but you need to check your server-side code, not the front one. Check the logs maybe ?

Comment: Have you tried to visit `http://yourdomainname.com/Registration/ReturnPartial` by typing the address in your browser url address bar and press enter? See if the login partial view is displayed in your browser.

Comment: @ Flo-Schield-Bobby I started writing this app 30 mins ago. so I have only these functions in my controllers and Views. of course I have _LogIn partial view too. nothing more yet.

Comment: thank you @ekad  I solved my problem. actually view are searched in ~Views/shared/_LogIn..cshtml,   ~Views/[controllername]/_LogIn.cshtml.
so I moved my _LogIn..cshtml from ~Views/Partial/_LogIn.cshtml to ~Views/Shared/__LogIn..cshtml and it works now

but what would I do if I don't won't to move my view from one folder to another?

Comment: @DatoMaisuradze, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't alert a general message "Failed to retrieve view". 
You should have alerted xhr.status and xhr.responseText at least, so you know whether you can't reach the server (client/url error) or the server couldn't return the response due to a server error.

Also make sure your general ErrorHandling (HandleErrorAttribute or Application_Error) logs all errors, so you can find all server errors and it's details.

Answer (score 0):

When you have this action method in `RegistrationController`

```
public ActionResult ReturnPartial()
{
    return PartialView("_LogIn");
}
```

make sure `_LogIn.cshtml` is located in `Views/Shared` folder or `Views/Registration` folder.

If you want to put `_LogIn.cshtml` in `Views/Partial` folder, then you can access the partial view by specifying the full path like below

```
public ActionResult ReturnPartial()
{
    return PartialView("~/Views/Partial/_LogIn.cshtml");
}
```